# Oracle session inactivity timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, session-timeout

I connect to my Oracle database using SQL developer.  The current idle time is set to 15 minutes of inactivity.  I have sys dba privileges.

In the database, I did the following:

```
Alter profile {the profile my account belongs to} limit IDLE_TIME 10;

COMMIT;
```

Then, I stopped and started the database for good measure.  Verified the idle time was still set to 10.  It was.

Back in SQL developer, I start a new database session, ran a query, got the intended results.  Stayed idle for 11 minutes, ran the same query once more, and it let me do so.  My session hadn't timed out.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***
I found out that I had to completely shutdown SQL developer and start it up once more for the changes to stick.